# Extarct SQL tables information Schema

Tags: mysql, sql, information-schema

I need to extract all the information in the tables given database. I have only one option to get all the information Schema are as;

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION.SCHEMA
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<table_name>'
```

but this is taking a lot more time consuming by extracting one by one, I need to get all the tables information schemas for one CSV file.

Comment: Your task isn't really clear. For one, if you want to get the information for all tables at once, use remove `where table_name` (and maybe replace it with `order by table_name`). For second, *"is taking a lot more time consuming by extracting one by one"* is unclear - if something there is slow, it will have to do with how you generate your csv (e.g. the code that you *didn't* show). Queries on the information schema are as fast as it gets. They are just a way to provide internal metadata that MySQL uses for its operation anyway - and MySQL requires this information vey fast too.

Comment: @Solarflare Yes, what i mean is in a database there are 100 tables with data. I need to get all the tables information schema using one query.